# How Quickly are Questions Closed Today?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I read the blurb for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204338/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-python-and-ruby-for-writing-web-applications) and clicked on it to vote to close. Of course, since I loaded the question in much slower than real time (I'm doing homework so I load the new questions on my breaks), it was already closed by the time I read the full question.

While reading the comments, I saw one that said `Closed under 60 seconds…`, which led me to wonder if there's a list anywhere of the questions that were closed the fastest; or maybe even a statistic in the site overview that talks about the average time-to-close for all questions closed today. Is there? Would this be useful?

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/84210/the-fastest-closed-questions. Winner was closed in 28 seconds and [has been deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487240), the [second place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522776/net-4-0-a-way-to-see-what-is-inside-the-produced-exe-file) was closed in 35 seconds. As for today, you'll need someone to do some API magic...

Comment: @TomWijsman But they were both mod-closed, that's cheating. What are the fastest closings without moderators or where the mod cast the fifth vote? That's the sport.

Comment: @DanielFischer: No, this query gives both.

Comment: @TomWijsman But I had to look manually through the results. And the winner is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046355/how-to-make-many-objects-into-single-objectc (in 61 seconds).

Comment: @DanielFischer: Well, if you need it, why don't you add a column and filter on it?

Comment: @TomWijsman I guess I would have to learn some SQL for that first.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Being lazy, that's cheating. Learning SQL? That's the sport. :D

Comment: @TomWijsman In a way, yes, but my masochism isn't bad enough to learn Perl yet, SQL must wait a few years more.

Comment: @DanielFischer, in a previous question I worked that one out to be 62 seconds... data.se doesn't include deleted questions though so it's academic. I think only a member of staff can find out for sure.

Answer (score 5):

With the addition of the table PostsWithDeleted we can now easily find the quickest closed question ever on a site. For Stack Overflow [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/744614) will give you the top 100 (time in milliseconds):

```sql
select top 100 datediff(ms, creationdate, closeddate) [milli seconds]
     , id as [Post Link]
     , creationdate
     , closeddate
     , deletiondate
from postswithdeleted
where closeddate is not null
and posttypeid = 1
and datediff(s, creationdate, closeddate) < 120
order by 1
```

Quickest ever closed was within 3177 ms. The top 2 are now deleted posts but the number 3 with 7376 ms is [how to fix my undefined index?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44887326) and was dupe hammered by [John Conde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/250259/john-conde).

You also ask for average time to close but that is not so interesting as it is rather big due to many outliers.

Instead I created a graph because we all like graphs. It is the log(seconds to close)/count():

[image]

We see a clear bump. I guess that is were we are looking for.

Comment: Logarithm base 10 or e?

Comment: @Desire base e as I used LOG() in T-Sql.

Comment: now did a log10 instead

Comment: The first two questions are actually not interesting. Those were test questions by one user immediately closing and deleting them. The #3 is the real winner here.